# mysql select with the same column appearing twice with different where clauses

Tags: mysql, select, pivot-table

I have a mysql table consisting of these columns:

user_id, start, end, district

Each user id has a start and end value in each district, like so:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| user_id | start | end  | district |
|       1 |  1000 | 2000 |    north |
|       1 |  1200 | 2200 |    south |
|       2 |   900 | 1900 |    north |
|       2 |   950 | 1700 |    south |
+-----------------------------------+
```

I am looking for a select that has one result row per user_id which lists the start and end for each of the two districts. Something like

```
select user_id,
(start as no_st, end as no_en where district='north'),
(start as so_st, end as so_en where district='south');
```

To give:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| user_id | no_st | no_en | so_st | so_en |
|       1 |  1000 |  2000 |  1200 |  2200 |
|       2 |   900 |  1900 |   950 |  1700 |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Is there a magic query for this?

Thanks,
Bart...

Comment: Have you done any research or tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one solution for a pivot query:

```
SELECT user_id, 
  MAX(IF(district='north', start, null)) AS no_st,
  MAX(IF(district='north', end, null)) AS no_en,
  MAX(IF(district='south', start, null)) AS so_st,
  MAX(IF(district='south', end, null)) AS so_en
FROM `NoOneEverNamesTheirTableInSQLQuestions`
GROUP BY user_id;
```